# Filter array based on presence in another array with different properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
let arr1 = [{itemId:1, name:"item1"}, {itemId:2, name:"item2"},{itemId:3, name:"item3"}]

let arr2 = [{id:1, name:"item1"}, {id:2, name:"item2"}]
```

How do I filter `arr1` based on whether there is a matching item in `arr2` where `arr1.itemId` will be equal to `arr2.id`

So expected result in this case would be:

```
[{itemId:1, name:"item1"}, {itemId:2, name:"item2"}]
```

I have tried searching SO so would be helpful if there is existing question if you could point me in right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const arr1 = [{itemId:1, name:"item1"}, {itemId:2, name:"item2"},{itemId:3, name:"item3"}];
const arr2 = [{id:1, name:"item1"}, {id:2, name:"item2"}];

const result = arr1.filter(({ itemId }) => arr2.some(x => x.id === itemId));

console.log(result);
```

This will work ok for small arrays, **however**, if the arrays get big, it is better to create a Set of ids from `arr2` and use `Set.prototype.has()` instead of `Array.prototype.some()`, this will run in *linear time* instead of *quadratic time*.

[See the response from **@Jonas Wilms**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504491/9325419).

Comment: i'll go with this one seeing as my array lengths are not that big but take on board @jonas wilms point.

Comment: @JimmyShoe, absolutely, I will refer to his answer

Answer (score 6):

Build up a Set of ids, than filter based on that:

```
 const ids = new Set(arr2.map(it => it.id));
 const result = array1.filter(it => ids.has(it.itemId));
```

Comment: Any advantage over jo_va's answer?

Comment: @eyecatchUp: jonas time = len(a) + len(b), jo_va's time = len(a) * len(b)

Comment: ... in other words: this runs in *linear time*, while other answers run in *exponential time*. You wont see a difference on little datasets, however if you run that over arrays with 100000 entries, you'll see why this one is better ... :)

Comment: @JonasWilms: well, "exponential" is a bit of exaggeration ;) I'd say "quadratic".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```js
let arr1 = [{itemId:1, name:"item1"}, {itemId:2, name:"item2"},{itemId:3, name:"item3"}];

let arr2 = [{id:1, name:"item1"}, {id:2, name:"item2"}];

let arr3 = arr1.filter(obj => arr2.some(other => obj.itemId == other.id));

console.log(arr3);
```

Which uses [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to loop and filter the elements that have a matching items in the second array, using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
arr1.filter(x=> arr2.some(y=>y.id==x.itemId));
```

```js
let arr1 = [{itemId:1, name:"item1"}, {itemId:2, name:"item2"},{itemId:3, name:"item3"}]
let arr2 = [{id:1, name:"item1"}, {id:2, name:"item2"}]


let r=arr1.filter(x=> arr2.some(y=>y.id==x.itemId));

console.log(r);
```